# name and message up and down and in lined with the icon

Tags: html, css

I know the title seems to sound really confusing but let me show through what Im trying to achieve.
This is the picture of what I'm trying to make.
[image: IMGUR image]

And this is what i'm getting as output of my code

[image: This is my output]

As you can see in the image no 1 the name "RomEio" and the text below are inline with the icon, but its not happening in my case..

```css
 

#onio_showmsg_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
#onio_showmsg_div > #showmsg_div1 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1);
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}
#msg_user {
    font-size: 12px;
}
#onio_user_2 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="onio_showmsg_div">
                <div id="showmsg_div1">
                    <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2"  style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <p>BaTuTa</p>
                        <span style="margin: 0px;padding:0px;">Na</span>
                    </div>
                </div>                      
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have too many divs, it can be accomplished much simpler:

```css
#onio_showmsg_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#onio_showmsg_div img {
    float: left;
}
.content {
    font-size: 12px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.content p
{
margin:0 0 5px 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="onio_showmsg_div">
  <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2"  style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
    <div class="content">
        <p>BaTuTa</p>
        <p><span>Na</span></p>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

I have move dthe `img` out of the floated container and it is now floated left itself. A container (`content`) is used to contain your text content and also explicitly float that to the left. The `overflow:hidden` on the main wrapper is a bit of a float hack to contain the floats.

Looking at other answers, i might be wise for you to learn about grid, and flexbox. As my answer is a bit old fashioned (using floats) but as your original question uses floats i did too.

Comment: Can you explain what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `line-height: 1px;` to the `<div style="display: inline-block;">` element's style.
This will set the space between each new line to `1px`.
Here is your code:

```css
#onio_showmsg_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
#onio_showmsg_div > #showmsg_div1 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1);
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}
#msg_user {
    font-size: 12px;
}
#onio_user_2 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="onio_showmsg_div">
                <div id="showmsg_div1">
                    <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2"  style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; line-height: 1px;">
                        <p>BaTuTa</p>
                        <span style="margin: 0px;padding:0px;">Na</span>
                    </div>
                </div>                      
            </div>
```

And here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/QWjKgPE?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

use flexbox for this kind of thing:

```css
#showmsg_div1 {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
#msg_user {
    font-size: 6px;
}


#f2{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:center;
}

p{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="showmsg_div1">
    <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2"  style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
    <div id='f2'style="display: inline-block;">
      <p>BaTuTa</p>
      <span style="margin: 0px;padding:0px;">Na</span>
    </div>
</div>
```